# This class is visible to consumers via SomeModule -> SomeComponent, but is not exported from the top-level library entrypoint

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular9

I upgraded all my angular library to `angular 9.0.0` using `ng update` and when I try to build them I got below error.

**Error:**

> Unsupported private class SomeComponent. This class is visible to consumers via SomeModule -> SomeComponent, but is not exported from the top-level library entrypoint.

Anyone solved this error?

Answer (score 260, accepted):

This error happens if any component is exported in `NgModule`and not included in your `public_api.ts`, `Angular 9` will throw an error now.

This error was not coming in `Angular 8` but after upgrading to `Angular 9` it started showing.

If you exported any `service`, `module` or `component`, etc in `NgModule` make sure to include them in `public_api.ts` or else `angular 9` will throw error now.

**Fix: add your component to the `public_api.ts`**

```
export * from './lib/components/some-me/some-me.component';
```

Comment: How would you include MaterialModule in this list of export statements ? Let me answer my question: `export * from './lib/material.module';`

Comment: Exporting module is not enough to use the internally exported components ??

Comment: @NandaKishoreAllu no, actually you need to add them in public_api to make them available.

Comment: If you are not using public_api.ts then editing index.ts works just as well.

Comment: Can someone perhaps explain this situation:
I have my component in a module and this module is being exported in public-api.ts, but when I try and do ng build I get the afforementioned message. Any guesses as to why this is happening?

Comment: Does this affect to both eager and lazy loaded modules? I assume only to eager, otherwise all internal components should be exported in public-api as they will be imported transitively in some part of the application, isn't it?

Comment: I only have a `public.ts` in `src/` , after adding `export * from "../src/collections/message/components/message"` it errors: `ERROR: Could not resolve '../src/collections/message/components/message' from dist/esm2015/public.js`

Answer (score 12):

I was struggling with the same issue today.

My prerequisites:

- I work on an Angular 11 library type project;
- I have added a new directive;
- I got an error as above when tried to add my directive to module exports.

Fix:

- I have added file export to index.ts file:

`export * from './just/a/relative/path/to/the/directive/{{myDirectiveFile}}';`

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue. I couldn't remove the default keyword, as Storybook required me to have that.  I ended up fixing it by changing this:

```
export * from './lib/components/some-me/some-me.component';
```

... to this:

```
export { default as SomeComponent } from './lib/components/some-me/some-me.component';
```

in the public_api.ts file.

Comment: such a pain if you have a bunch of directives or components in your library but I guess is a good evil :)

Answer (score 1):

This error happened to me because I used the `default` keyword to export my component :

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss'],
})
export default class FormComponent implements OnInit {
    // ...
}
```

The use of this keyword was suggested by my Linter and allows to write imports as `import FormComponent from './form.component';` instead of `import { FormComponent } from './form.component';`

However this does not seem to work well along `public-api.ts`. The solution for me was to remove the `default` keyword and change all imports.

Comment: I think you saved me hours of searching for the cause of this problem, which was the default exports :)