# 'Unsupported private class xy' while building Angular library

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-packagr

I'm developing an npm package with Angular. While building the lib, I get the following error:

> Unsupported private class MyLibComponent. This class is visible to consumers via MyLibModule -> MyLibComponent, but is not exported from the top-level library entrypoint.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60121962/this-class-is-visible-to-consumers-via-somemodule-somecomponent-but-is-not-e). This explains how I fix it, but not why I need to put all components in the barrel file as the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule#exports) for NgModules says:

> Exported declarations are the module's public API.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Did you read my question? ;)

Answer (score -2):

Please make sure that the component has been exported to your `public-api.ts` as:

```
export * from './lib/my-lib/my-lib.component';
```

and export the component from your library module, too.

Comment: Did you read my question?